# Load a list into python tkinter, and create a button for each line

Tags: python, tkinter

So I found this piece of code, and it does everything I need, but I would like it to import the names of each button from a list on my desktop called sample, but how?

```
import functools
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def func(name):
    print (name)
mylist = ['item1','item2','item3']
for item in mylist:
    button = Button(root,text=item,command=functools.partial(func,item))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a Python list on your desktop?

Comment: Your question would probably be best answered by reading the documentation on [file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: I got a text file on my desktop called sample

Comment: Opening and reading files is well documented and there are countless examples on the internet. It's not clear why you need help here instead of using available documentation.

Comment: I am asking because I couldn't get it to work, however I haven't read the file I/O, but I will do that now, and thx for pointing me towards it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a text file of button names, maybe like so:

**`sample.txt`**

```
item1
item2
item3
```

Then you can use

```py
mylist = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    mylist = file.readlines()
```

to fill `mylist` with the names. As mentioned by @Christian Dean, its worth reading up on file I/O anyway.

Comment: Every item in the list will contain trailing `'\n'`.  Better use `mylist = file.read().splitlines()` or `mylist = [line.strip() for line in file]` instead.